# How good it is to use Magento XML connect api for developing mobile apps?

Tags: magento2, mobile, android, app

I am new to magento development and need suggestions and experience. For an ecommerce store for target platforms (Web + Mobile).

For a highly customizable mobile apps. Is the Magento's XML Connect API a perfect choice ?